# Mailing list for internships and full time jobs for computer science PhD students

Tags: computer-science, job-search, email, industry, internship

I have found many mailing lists for conferences. I just want to know: is there any mailing list that updates internship and full-time positions (computer science industry jobs and academic jobs) for Ph.D. students? Would you please tell me what are those? Any location would work for me.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Academia.SE!  Can you please specify what field you are looking for, since different fields have different ways they organize themselves.

Comment: As it stands, this question can only be answered with *yes* – there is at least one such mailing list. If you want to ask about a mailing list for your specific country and subfield, however, it is too localised – you better ask others in your field. Either way, it’s not a question we can satisfyingly answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For computer science, the [CRA computing jobs](http://cra.org/ads/) site is a good central clearinghouse for a large fraction of faculty postings and some non-faculty research positions.  For industrial jobs in computer science, however, there is no such central location.